# Javascript search an array for a value starting with a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, startswith

I am looking for a way to search an array to see if a value is present that starts with the search term.

```
const array1 = ['abc','xyz'];
```

So a search for 'abcd' would return true on the above.

I have been playing about with includes, but that only seems to check the full value.
Also, startsWith I dont think will work as I believe that checks a string and not values in an array??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function which allows you to pass a custom function in parameter that will be tested on each value. This way you can use `startsWith()` on each value of the array as you intended to do.

Example:

```js
const array1 = ['abc','xyz'];

function findStartWith(arg) {
  return array1.find(value => {
    return arg.startsWith(value);
  });
}

console.log(findStartWith("hello")); // undefined
console.log(findStartWith("abcd")); // abc
console.log(findStartWith("xyzz")); // xyz
```

If you want to return `true` or `false` instead of the value, you can check if the returned value is different from `undefined`.

```js
function findStartWith(arg) {
  return !!array1.find(value => {
    return arg.startsWith(value);
  }) !== undefined;
}
```

The same snippet with a boolean:

```js
const array1 = ['abc','xyz'];

function findStartWith(arg) {
  return array1.find(value => {
    return arg.startsWith(value);
  }) !== undefined;
}

console.log(findStartWith("hello")); // false
console.log(findStartWith("abcd")); // true
console.log(findStartWith("xyzz")); // true
```